# How to split list of strings into two columns and append it to a spire pdf in c#

Tags: list, c#-4.0, pdf-generation

```
This is my list of data type string:
List<string> Questions = new List<string>(); 

I am appending list of static questions ,answers to the question values from model 
Questions .Add("Q1? " + " : " + model.value);
Questions .Add("Q2?" + " : " + model.value);

string[][] datasource = new String[Questions .Count][];

  for (int i = 0; i < Questions .Count; i++)
            {
                datasource[i] = Questions [i].Split(';');
            }
```

Appending it to spire pdf table:

PdfTable table = new PdfTable();
table.DataSource = datasource;

MY output:
What type of tax return does the entity file? : 604 --In single column
Expected output:
column1                                         column2
What type of tax return does the entity file?    604

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kindly note that there's only one set of data in every element of the array "Questions", thus the table only has a single column. If you want the expected output of two columns, please change your code as:

```
string[] Questions = { "Q1?:;model.value", "Q2?:;model.value" };
```